# Sort array of dates from earlier date to "younger" date

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I'm writing a method that sorts the dates in order from "oldest" to "youngest".

In the first cell of the array will be the earliest date.

Empty cells (containing zeros) will be at the end of the array.

Functions:

- `firstfree()` first date in array of dates that is "zero", if it is non-zero it returns -1.
- `isfree()` -> if date is "zero" return true

**Problem: it doesn't change all dates in from "oldest to youngest"**.

```
void Calendar::sortDates()
{
    MyDate *Date_S;
    MyDate zero;
    int index = 0;
    int sumDigit = 0;
    Date_S = new MyDate[29]; // max 30 days by defention of exercise
    if (this->firstFree() == -1) //array of "zero"
    {
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<29; i++)  // moving dates not "zero" to Dates_S
            if (this->isFree(i + 1) == false)
            {
                Date_S[index] = Dates[i];
                index++;
            }


        for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 29 - j - i; j++)
            {
                if (Date_S[j].isBefore(Dates[j + 1]) == false) // bubble sort of Dates_S in 
                {
                    zero = Date_S[j];
                    Date_S[j] = Date_S[j + 1];
                    Date_S[j + 1] = zero;
                }
            }
        }
        for (index; index < 30; index++) // copying "zero" dates to the end of Dates_S
        {
            Date_S[index].setZero();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) // shallow copy , just integers
        {
            Dates[i] = Date_S[i];
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like this is not a real question, but rather an experiment in posting a stack overflow snippet.

Comment: Are those dates initialized? It looks like every part of this is already in the standard library. Dates, containers, sorting. Maybe even a partition depending on what that "zero" stuff is.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I've removed the Javascript/CSS code formatting that you were using for the snippet and fixed the indentation. Then I've grouped the description of the code and of the problem at the top, and left the code at the bottom. Moreover, I've added the bubble-sort tag this question is about. Now the question is easier to answer, though I think you should [edit] it again and add a [mcve]. Good luck!